# Remove CSS from SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL query that extracts data from the source system, and the data is formatted in CSS format so it contains text along with things such as < p > blah blah < / p >

Is there any simple way to remove all of these?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: That's not CSS, that's HTML.  So are you just asking how to strip HTML tags from a string?

Comment: Yes apologies, I just want the text..not the bits of code